# How to insert text in an existing file?

Tags: c++, file-io

Example, I have a `sample.txt` file with content:

```
1 2 3 7 8 9 10
```

and I want to insert `4 5 6`in file to have

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

so that numbers are inserted in the right place.

Comment: I updated the title to make it clearer

Comment: May I ask where you will be using this for? I suggest storing the values in an array in a json file might be a safer choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files generally don't support inserting text in the middle. You should read the file, update the contents and overwrite the file.

Use a sorted container, e.g. `std::set` to hold the contents of the file in memory.

```
std::set<int> contents;

// Read the file
{
    std::ifstream input("file");
    int i;
    while (input >> i)
        contents.insert(i);
}

// Insert stuff
contents.insert(4);
contents.insert(5);
contents.insert(6);

// Write the file
{
    std::ofstream output("file");
    for (int i: contents)
        output << i << ' ';
}
```